# Create project template in visual studio 2012 with more stuffs?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-sdk

I know how to create a project templates in visual studio.
My question is about that;

How to create a Project Template like Asp.net MVC?

When you create a project with Asp.net MVC, you'll have Razor syntax stuff like intellisense, There is a directly access to add Views and Controllers and a lot of thing to help the other programmers.

Comment: This question cannot be answered in this format. It's way to broad. Read a good book or tutorial site.

Comment: @nvoigt just a book or resource or search keyword if you know will be so helpfull, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean, search keyword? How about putting your subject line into google?

Comment: The ASP.NET MVC stuff is open source, go check it out: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MSDN check out the documentation on:

- [Custom Project and Item Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247119.aspx).
- [The IWizard interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301.aspx)
- [Custom editors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166329.aspx)
- [General Visual Studio.NET Extensibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165336.aspx)

And last but not least, since you're already quoting [the ASP.NET MVC project as your example, it's open source and you can see how it's done right on codeplex](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/.).

Comment: the source Asp.net MVC was so helpful. thanks